# Find those files with an underscore that have no matching file without underscore in shell?

Tags: bash, str-replace

I have got files like `klein_parat-strong-aqua-stop.jpg`. Most of them have a counterpart with all underscores replaced with a minus, `klein-parat-strong-aqua-stop.jpg` for example.

Some of them however do not have that counterpart. I want to find those files in a folder including its subfolders. How would I do that?

THanks!

Comment: See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for the way to perform string replacement in shell variables. From there the rest should be obvious.

Comment: Did you make some efforts on your own?

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

Try this two commands

```
for FF in `find . -type f -name "*_*" `;do echo $FF;done > list
for II in `<list`;do I=`basename $II`;F2=`echo $I | tr '_' '-'`;FOUND=`find . -name "$F2"`;[ "$FOUND" == "" ] && { echo $II; };done
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea would be find all files first and then test the existence of the counterpart, as mentioned in the comment:

```
for i in `find . -name '*_*'`
do
    test -f "${i//_/-}" || echo "$i"
done
```

A one-liner:

```sh
for i in `find . -name '*_*'`; do test -f "${i//_/-}" || echo "$i"; done
```

`test -f file`: check whether `file` is a normal file or not.